# Linear programming with a product term in the objective function

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

The title might sound a little weird. I actually want to ask if this problem can be solved as a LP. And if so, how to convert the product term?

set $P=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ for index $i$. Variables $B_i$ and $x_i$ are both indexed by $i$. $x_i$ is binary variable.  All the constraints can be converted to linear constraints.

The objective is :

$\min \sum B_i x_i  $, where $x_i$ is binary.

I know is the product term is in the constraints, then we can use the big-M coefficient to convert it to linear constraints. Is there a way to do this when the product term is in the objective function? Thank you.

PS: Both $B_i$ and $x_i$ are variables.There are many other decision variables and about 20 linear constraints. but other variables are not in the objective function so I didn't list them

Comment: To clarify, by binary variable you don't mean you are in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but that you are identifying this with 0 and 1 (or something like that). Otherwise that minimum would be nonsense.

Comment: so the $B_i$ are fixed and the $x_i$ are the variables?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. both of them are variables and $x_i$ is 0-1 variable

Answer (score 4):

To linearize the product
$
B_ix_i
$ in your objective function, 
replace it by $y_{i}$ and add the following constraints:
\begin{cases}
y_{i}\le Mx_{i}\\
y_{i}\le B_{i}\\
y_{i}\ge B_i-M(1-x_i) \\
y_{i}\ge 0
\end{cases}
$M$ is a large constant. If $x_i=0$, it is easy to see that you will have $y_i=0$. And if $x_i=1$, you will have $y_i=B_i$.

Note: I assumed your variable $B_i$ is bounded below by $0$ already.

Comment: That's amazing!! How do you compose this @Kuifje ? Is there a compilation somewhere of all these tricks in linear programming? Thank you very much.

Comment: I personally learned a lot through my different courses via many different references. But to be honest, type "linearize product" on google and the first link will give you the trick I wrote :)

Comment: Two lists of tricks I found very useful are: https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_IntegerProgrammingTricks.pdf (see section 7.7 for your question regarding elimination of products) + 
https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_LinearProgrammingTricks.pdf